# ax2012 ssrs grouping condition based on a parameter

Tags: group-by, ssrs-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I've to print SalesPackingSlip report and only if SalesOrder has a specific value on a custom field I've to Group by itemId, else I shouldn't Group on ITEM ID even if I've twice the same item. 
I've used a boolean parameter on the contract that is true only when I want to Group on itemId. 
To condition the grouping on this parameter I wrote in the General Group properties this expression:

```
iif(parameters!isEDISalesOrder.value = 'true', 
Fields!ItemId.Value,Nothing)
```

[image]

but it doesn't work.
Could you help me some way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider taking the [tour] and reading [ask] to get some information on how you can improve your chances to receive a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put that parameter into a text box by itself and run the report, then make sure that your iif statement matches whats coming through from the parameter (be it True or 1 or whatever.)